# Spread syntax ecmascript

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've used spread syntax before, but not in this way. I am confused over the jump between `(...fns)` to `(...args)`. I understand that `fns` is the functions that are passed in (internalOnLoad and onLoad), and that the `args` are the arguments which belongs to the corresponding function. But how would it look like when each function are passing their arguments to the function (...args) => fns.forEach(...) ?

```
const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));

const internalOnLoad = () => console.log("loaded");

const Avatar = ({ className, style, onLoad, ...props }) => (
  <img 
    className={`avatar ${className}`}
    style={{ borderRadius: "50%", ...style }}
    onLoad={callAll(internalOnLoad, onLoad)}
    {...props} 
  />
);

Avatar.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  alt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object,
  onLoad: PropTypes.func
};
```

Can you give me a visual description of how this would look like? E.g. that calling `callAll = (...fns)` like this: `callAll(internalOnLoad, onLoad)` is the same as callAll will receive the arguments like this `callAll = (internalOnLoad, onLoad)`

Thank you in advance

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 5):

The [rest parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) collects all arguments into an array. In this case [partial application](https://hackernoon.com/partial-application-of-functions-dbe7d9b80760) is used to store an array of functions (`fns`), and return a new function. When the new function is called, it will invoke the functions in `fns`, and pass the arguments (`args`) to each one of them.

If we use the standard JS functions, it would be:

```
function callAll(...fns) { 
    return (...args) {
        fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```js
const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));

const callFns = callAll (
  (a, b) => console.log(a + b + 10),
  (a, b) => console.log(a + b + 20),
  (a, b) => console.log(a + b + 30),
);

console.log(callFns); // you can see the function that was returned in the console.

callFns(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));`

The first `...` gets all functions.

The second `...` gets all arguments.

The third `...` inserts the arguments with `fn.apply(undefined, args)` into the function instead of `fn(args)`.